# Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should reinstall it before attempting configuration

Tags: synaptic

```
E: gdebi: Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should  reinstall it before attempting configuration.

E: photostory: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

E: pyscreenie: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: Try `dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f`.